# What is the correct form of href attribute in <a> tag while working with Apache mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, href

I want to make my URL clean. Below is what I want to do:
Dirty URL: `www.site.com/index.php?page=products`
Clean URL: `www.site.com/products/`

For this, I write these codes in .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.php?page=$1
```

But whenever I click on the links in my project, I redirect to `localhost` page. Links are in this form:

```
<a href="products">Products</a>
```

I think it may be related to `href` value.
What's the correct form for `href` value? `href="product"`,`href="/product/"`,etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no correct form for your href attribute, each form acts in different ways:

```
<a href="products">Products</a>
```

The above would go relatively from the page you are currently on, so might be `domain.com/products` but might be `domain.com/shop/products`

You are better using a link direct from the root by using a `/` at the start, for example:

```
<a href="/products">Products</a>
```

would go to `domain.com/products` (note the lack of a `/` at the end of the url, which will make it not work with your current htaccess rule)

To make both `/products` and `/products/` go to the correct place, change your htaccess rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?page=$1
```

The `?` will make the character preceding it optional, so the `/` in this case.

Comment: Thank you @Nick for your valuable answer. Just please tell me is there any role for `RewriteBase /` here for what I said?

Comment: As I put `?` mark, I redirect to localhost when I want to lunch website :(